# Cast a List of super class to sub class

Tags: list, class, encapsulation

I have three classes A , B , C.

Class A has a method that returns a list of class B.

For example,

```
A a = new A();

List<B> b = a.getListofA();
```

There is another method `doSomeinB()` in class B.
I extended class C from class B and added a new method in C, `doSomeinC()`, now I called `a.getListofA()` which returns a list of B, how can i use `doSomeinC()`.

Comment: Does A inherit from B? Your explanation is somewhat vague. Explain the class relationships a little better please.

Comment: What programming language is this in?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I've got it that:

`A` is a subclass of `B` 
`C` is a subclass of `B`.

And from your question, it seems that you want to use a method in class `C`, on objects of type `B`. This will not work, because `B` does not know the methods in `C`; `B` is the parent class. `C` knows everything about `B`, but not the other way around. To use methods in `C`, you could say:

```
List<C> c = c.getListOfC();
// That's right. You'll need to make this method.
c.doSomeInC();
```

or you could refer to it as an instance of it's parent:

```
List<B> b = c.getListOfC();
```

---

Side note, have a look at the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). Some of your method names don't conform to spec, e.g:

```
getListofC --> getListOfC
```